# Phase plane plotting in R using fda package phaseplanePlot command

Tags: r, plot, functional-programming, label

So I am trying to compute a phase plane plot of some functional data, its is measured against time so I want the labels on the plot to mark every 12 hours.

```
attach(alldata)

#identify the time measure form the data, and make a vector
tdata<-data.matrix(alldata[,1:1])

timev<-as.vector(tdata)

#identify the control group
control<-data.matrix(alldata[,2:25])

#create basis and smooth and create functional object
basis17<-create.fourier.basis(rangeval=c(0,5.24677083333333), nbasis=17)

csbasis17<-smooth.basis(argvals=tdata,control,basis17)

controlfd<-fd(coef(csbasis17),basis17) 

#creaste list of points whre i was labels to go and name them 

th<-list("12 hours"=timev[1:1],"24 hours"=timev[15:15],"36 hours"=timev[29:29],"48 hours"=timev[43:43],
         "60 hours"=timev[50:50], "72 hours"=timev[57:57], "84 hours"=timev[71:71],
         "96 hours"=timev[85:85] ,"108 hours"=timev[100:100],"120 hours"=timev[114:114], "136 hours"=timev[128:128])
#crerate list of 2 containing the points i want plotted and the names
ws<- list(th,labels(th))

#phase plane plot command 
phaseplanePlot(timev,controlfd,Lfdobj1=1, Lfdobj2=2,
               lty=c("longdash", "solid"),
               labels=ws)
```

This produces the following plot, with no labels?

[image]

and this is what comes up in the error bar

```
Error in text.default(D1., D2., labels$labels) : 
  no coordinates were supplied
```

I cant figure out how to fix it??

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I don't think you need to call `attach(alldata)` (actually noboby needs `attach` most of the time...). To quickly explain what `attach(obj)` function does in layman's terms: it just takes all the variables inside `obj` (that can be a list or data.frame or environment) and copy them into the global environment. So if `obj` contains a variable (or column) named `foo`, besides calling `obj$foo`, after `attach(obj)`, you can also use directly `foo`

Comment: Regarding your problem, we need a reprodubible example: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some tricks to make your problem reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put the `th` into a list. As your example is not reproducible, assume e.g. that the length is 1:100, the first 100 evaluated points of the curve and we want to plot a label in the origen `"O"`, middle `"M"` and the end `"E"` of our data. Then, you should fill the `label` argument as follows:

```
arg <- 1:100

phaseplanePlot(timev,controlfd, Lfdobj1 = 1, Lfdobj2 = 2,
               lty = c("longdash", "solid"),
               label = list(evalarg = seq(arg[1], max(arg), length=3), 
                            labels = c("O","M","E"))
```

Here,

```
seq(arg[1], max(arg), length=3) 
[1]   1.0  50.5 100.0
```

Then,
[image]